# Salesforce webserver Oauth 2.0 integration

Tags: oauth, salesforce

I am developing a google app engine - java project where I want to integrate Salesforce APIs.
I want to authorize user with Oauth 2.0 and want to retrieve contacts of the authorized user.

Salesforce API returns code in response of the first request and then again I request for the access token from the code.

With the access token when I call any of the service API it gives me following error

```
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.
In configurations Administration Profile was missing to be connected with Apps whose client ID and secret I was using.

Answer (score 0):

you are not getting valid access token.
generate the proper url to get the access token

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_at_Salesforce.com

For more proper information, you can have a look of [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/OAuthServlet.java)